# UnicodeEncodeError: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with this code I'm  running in PyCharm with Python 3.4.
The variable `html_text` stops functioning when I pass it to BeautifulSoup (I'm using BeautifulSoup4).

The error message is:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 52793: character maps to <undefined>

Why is it so and how can it be solved?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://nytimes.com'

urls = [url]  # stack of urls
visited = [url]  # already visited urls to avoid revisiting

while len(urls) > 0:
    try:
        html_text = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
    except:
        print(urls[0])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html5lib')
    urls.pop(0)
```

Comment: Can you `print(repr(html_text[:128]))` so we can get a feel for what's in there. Also, grab the response object from `urlopen(...)` and `print(response.getheaders())`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, if you can give us the url causing the problem we can try it for ourselves.

Comment: ...and the [urllib.request docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse) say _The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface_. There is wisdom in that advice!

Comment: Can't reproduce. This code works for me and since OP isn't sharing any additional information, there isn't much we can do.

Comment: My problem here is mainly at the point where I call the variable html_text to BeautifulSoup, Pycharm for examlple tell's me the variable cannot be defined and that error pops up on run

Comment: @tdelaney: here html_text[:128] - b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> <!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js edition-domestic app-homepage"  itemscope xmlns:og='

Comment: I tried your code again and no problems. The only way I can think that you would get a `charmap` error is if you are running in a Windows console and tried to view the html. If the doc has a character that is not in your code page, I think you'd get this. I don't use Windows or pycharm so nothing definitive! Your code works for me on linux and should work on windows if called as a script from cmd.exe. As long as it doesn't try to print the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I changed some few crabs related to html view and now it runs perfectly.